# Uninstall and reinstall app causes duplicate push messages firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving duplicate notification when I Uninstall and reinstall app,

Ex I have version 2 of app register to get notifications from topic XXXX after that I will Uninstall app and Reinstall verion 3 APP subscribe to same XXXX topic 
I am getting same notifications Twice.

Is Firebase sends notifications for the older app?
Any Suggestions how to handle this or how to clean up earlier session

I am seeing same issue in Both iOS and Andriod

Comment: Yes, a new firebase token is generated each time you uninstall and re install the app. I supposed you are using firebase console for sending the messages. In order to avoid that, you need to make your own backend which would internally use firebase api's to send messages and you at your backend would have a mapping of device id with firebase token[Against a device id], each time you receive a new token, you need to update or insert it based on the entry of device id you have

Comment: thanks for input,
I am using my own server only, Since I am using topics feature of Firebase to broadcast  notifications. Whenever I send the notifications to firebase its keeping track of old app also and sending it to both

Comment: Looked once again into your question. Of course new tokens are generated  and that means that the old ones are invalidated. So ideally you should not receive duplicate notifications unless there is a flaw in the logic somewhere.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your app server code and client app code for receiving the messages. And as mentioned in my comment in the answer below, uninstalling the app *invalidates* the corresponding token, making it unusable.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you delete app and install it again. Replaced old FCM token of with new FCM token. Means every time you get FCM token from user and store it on server or firebase check whether FCM token for that user is already present or not. If present then replace it. If not add it.

Comment: thanks for the input, Since I am using topics feature of Firebase to broadcast notifications replacing it the token will not slove it. Whenever I send the notifications to firebase its keeping track of old app also and sending it to both

Comment: Then you need to keep track of device id and link FCM token with it. Before adding FCM token to server check both device id and FCM token, if you find FCM token for particular device id then delete first then add new. From this server will know app is deleted from particular device and stop sending to that device and will treat new device on installation.

Comment: Uninstalling the app *invalidates* the corresponding token. So it shouldn't really produce a duplicate behavior after the app is re-installed.

Comment: @AL. Even I also thought the same but it's not happening, anyway I have filed the bug in firebase end let see

Answer (score 0):

Also check your topic name creation logic , is there a dynamic part to it ? Like topicName+grpname , you may be unknowingly subscribing to multiple topics hence getting suplicate messages meant for multiple topics .